# In Android, How can I display an application selector based on file type?

Tags: android

Apologies if this has already been answered - if someone can point me to an already-answered question, that would be great...

Very simply, I would like to be able to pop up a list of applications which can process a file of a given type - for instance, if I have a music file (mp3, ogg, whatever), I'd like to be able to display a list of all loaded media applications that can process the file and allow the user to select one.

I've been playing around with creating an intent to do this as follows:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
myIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
myIntent.setType("mp3");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

but I've obviously gotten it wrong, since it crashes every time. Should I be using ACTION_PICK or ACTION_CHOOSER instead of ACTION_VIEW?

More importantly, is it possible to easily define all media players by something other than the Intent.type? I believe type should be a proper MIME type, in lower case, but I'm not sure what to use in this instance...

Please be gentle :)

Comment: Pinging this to see if anyone has an answer (even a partial answer)...

Comment: I had a similar issue. I used the following solution to get an application chooser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635764/application-selection-dialog-based-on-filetype This solution also takes away the need of building your own dialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the applications that can successfully open a given intent you'll use the PackageManager.  Simply construct the intent as above and then use this code to get the applications that can handle the intent.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
myIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
myIntent.setType("mp3");    

PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> info = manager.queryIntentActivities(
    myIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

This will give you all the information on the programs that can handle the intent, including icon, and packagename. You can then create a dialog box with these options and save the option the user chooses.

Comment: By "the intent as above", you mean @sstn's code? In this case, you mean use your package manager code **instead** of startActivity()?

Comment: right.  Then that'll give you all the info you need.  Let me clean up the code a bit.

Comment: That looks great! I don't suppose you have any code for an appropriate dialog box hanging about, do you? Or do I simply create my own 'standard' one?

Comment: You'll just create your own standard one.  I'd choose an alert dialog. Check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to see this chooser dialog if you do open a file (or URL) and there is more than one application registered to handle it? E.g. you open a youtube URL and can chose to use the youtube player or browser?

That is the kind of intent the system sends when I want to open an image (through the file browser):

```
File f = new File("/sdcard/IMG_0114.JPG");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
// use setDataAndType() - setData() and setType() cancel each other
i.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
i.putExtra("preview", false);
i.putExtra("key_filename", "/sdcard/IMG_0114.JPG");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
i.putExtra("sort_order", 0);

// It's one of the flag combinations:
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION);

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK |
        Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION);

startActivity(i);
```

EDIT: corrected code to get a working (minimal) solution.

I am not sure which fields of the extra data has to be set - didn't find documentation for that.

Comment: you're correct that I want to see the chooser dialog. However, I don't actually want to open the file (indeed, I'm not actually going to have a specific file) - I want to be able to return the method that would be used to open that file.

Comment: Basically, I want to pop up a chooser for a file **type** and then be able to save (in my application) the name of the chosen application. Does that make sense?