# Application selection dialog based on filetype

Tags: android, android-dialog

I'm trying to create a Dialog, which will display a list of availible applications to open a given filetype.

I've been looking at some question here on stackoverflow that work with the same issue, but I get lost due to lacking answer. In particular I've been looking at this question:

[In Android, How can I display an application selector based on file type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834374/in-android-how-can-i-display-an-application-selector-based-on-file-type)

My follow-up question is then:

- What to do with the `List<ResolveInfo>`?
- How can I display the availible applications with name and icon?
- When the user selects an application, how can I start it based on the ResolveInfo of the selected item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, that gives me a full list of applications that can open a given mimetype. It's not the best, as I would like the list to be more specific and just a few applications (e.g. if it was an URL I wanted to open only browsers would show up) but serves the purpose.

Here is what I did:

```
File file = new File( "myFileLocation.txt" );
String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl( file.getPath() );
String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), type );    
context.startActivity( intent );
```

Comment: Add this code just before startActivity
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List activities =
                packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

        if (!isIntentSafe)
            toast("No App Available for:\n" + fileName);
        else