# How can I send the user to a video player in Android?

Tags: android, video

I have read this article:
[Sending the User to Another App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html)

If user click on a button, and they should be sent to a video player to watch the video, could anyone please tell me what I should put in the Intent's constructor? I have the path of an mp4 file as `String`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5043858/1778834 this might help you.

Answer (score 2):

try following code

```
File file=new File(filepath);
Uri uriToFile=Uri.fromFile(file);

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToFile);
shareIntent.setType("*/mp4");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Send to"));
```